# Setting up sqlcipher in an electron app using electron-forge and webpack

Tags: sqlite, webpack, electron, sqlcipher, electron-forge

I am trying to open a **sqlite3** database encrypted with **sqlcipher**. I have the password and I could open it successfully using sqlitebrowser.

I started my project using [this template](https://github.com/diego3g/electron-typescript-react). It is based on the *electron-forge* webpack plugin.

When I type `yarn start`, it creates a *.webpack* folder and all the compiled code goes in it. When I stop the terminal command, this folder disappears.

Then I wanted to use the package [@journeyapps/sqlcipher](https://github.com/journeyapps/node-sqlcipher) to open my database, but this line is causing an error in the main process: `const sqlite3 = require("@journeyapps/sqlcipher")`

The error is:
`Error: Cannot find module '<<my_path>>/.webpack/main/native_modules/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64/node_sqlite3.node'`

---

The package documentation says two things about using it with electron-forge:

1. make sure that the folder *node_modules/@journeyapps/sqlcipher/lib/binding/napi-v6-linux-x64* exists
   -> yes it exists
2. Disable rebuilding of this library using the onlyModules option of electron-rebuild in your package.json `"config": { "forge": { "electronRebuildConfig": {  "onlyModules": []  // Specify other native modules here if required  } }`
   -> I did it, I added the lines of code

I still have the error, but I feel it can be solved "easily" (with a lot more understanding of webpack than I have). Indeed, a solution would be to move the folder *binding/napi-v6-linux-x64* into *.webpack* each time I launch the app, right?

---

I tried to do `electron-rebuild -f -w sqlite3`, the rebuild succeeded but nothing happens, I still have the same error.

---

I am stuck here and cannot go further for my app, as it lays on reading this database.
Should I start a new project and avoid using webpack? Do you have any example of a project where this package is successfully imported and used?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I finally figured it out. Actually, I tried so much little changes but I managed to make the app work (nearly) as expected.

### How I found the solution

First: this doesn't have anything to do with the library sqlcipher itself. In fact, it's a webpack configuration problem while dealing with native libraries.

I started a fresh minimal install of electron-forge with Webpack and Typescript template (`npx create-electron-app test-electron-forge-github --template=typescript-webpack`) and added *sqlite3* and *@journeyapps/sqlcipher*. It worked so I made a lot of changes in my Webpack configuration to make it closer with the electron-forge one.

### Warning

The changes I made broke *Redux*. I chose to sacrifice *Redux* in order to make *sqlcipher* work, as today I didn't find a solution for both of them to work.

### Old Webpack configuration files

**main.webpack.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  },
  entry: './electron/main.ts',
  module: {
    rules: require('./rules.webpack'),
  }
}
```

**renderer.webpack.js**

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.tsx', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    rules: require('./rules.webpack'),
  },
}
```

**rules.webpack.js**

```js
module.exports = [
    {
        test: /\.node$/,
        use: 'node-loader',
    },
    {
        test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
        parser: { amd: false },
        use: {
            loader: '@marshallofsound/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
            options: {
                outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
            },
        },
        resolve: {
            fullySpecified: false,
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader',
        ]
    },
]
```

### New configuration

**main.webpack.js**

```js
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    entry: './electron/main.ts',
    module: {
        rules: [
            ...require('./rules.webpack'),

            {
                test: /\.(m?js|node)$/,
                parser: { amd: true },
                use: {
                    loader: '@vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader',
                    options: {
                        outputAssetBase: 'native_modules',
                        emitDirnameAll: true,
                    },
                }
            },
        ],
    }
}
```

The native modules configuration has been moved from *rules.webpack.js* to *main.webpack.js*. This is due to a bug happening in the renderer process if the rule stayed in the *rules.wepback.ts* file.
The window would open but would stay blank. In the console, there would be an error: `__dirname is not defined`. See this [Github issue](https://github.com/vercel/webpack-asset-relocator-loader/issues/97) from where I took the solution.

Also note that I changed the loader as the previous one was not doing properly its job.

**renderer.webpack.js**
Unchanged

**rules.webpack.js**

```js
module.exports = [
    {
        // We are specifying native_modules in the test because the asset relocator loader generates a
        // "fake" .node file which is really a cjs file.
        test: /native_modules\/.+\.node$/,
        use: 'node-loader',
    },
    {
        test: /\.(js|ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
            loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
    },
    {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
            name: '[path][name].[ext]',
        },
    },
    {
        test: /\.(sass|less|css)$/,
        use: [
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader',
            'postcss-loader',
            'sass-loader',
        ]
    },
]
```

### Redux

I had to remove this property from *rules.webpack.js*:

```js
resolve: {
    fullySpecified: false,
}
```

This line was making *Redux* work.

### Conclusion

I don't really know how this works, but it works. I hope it will help you if you are struggling as I was.